Information about novel 'heavy weapons'
The story is about an inspector trying to find old artillery that used black holes to fire shells. The locals have been using them as a garbage dump. Who was the author, where did it appear?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is there more to the plot than this?  It seems a bit thin for an entire novel.  When and where did you read it?  Do you remember the cover art?

How sure are you about the title? https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=weapons&type=Fiction+Titles

@DavidW - It was a 7000-ish word short story.

This is The Clockwork Atom Bomb by Dominic Green. A weapons inspector comes across some errant black holes that were being used to propel shells great distances during a brushfire war in a third-world country.

You remember that outbreak of airborne rabies in New Zealand two years
back? That was one of theirs. A Congolese shell fired too hot and went
into orbit. The orbit decayed. The shell came down. Thirteen years
after the war. Gunpowder and magnetism don’t do that.”
“So what was it?”
“A Penrose accelerator. You get yourself a heavy-duty rotating mass,
big enough to have stuff orbit round it, and you whirl ordnance round
those orbits, contrary to the direction of the mass’s rotation. Half
of your ordnance separates from the payload, and drops into the mass.
The other half gets kicked out to mind-buggering velocities. The
trouble is, none of this works unless the mass is dense enough to have
an escape velocity greater than light.”
“A black hole.”
“Yes. You have yourself thirty-nine charged rotating black holes,
formerly used as artillery accelerators, now with nowhere to go. Plus
another hole lodged precariously on the back of a tractor on the
public highway halfway between here and Djelo-Binza. And the only way
for us to find enough energy to get rid of them, I imagine, would be
to use another black hole to kick them into orbit. They also give off
gamma, almost constantly, as they’re constantly absorbing matter. You
point one of those UxB defuser tractors at them and throw the safety
on the gun, and – ”

The story contains the words "Heavy Weapons" in capitalised letters, but this wasn't the title.

“I’m telling you, there are at least forty of them. I counted them.
Five rows by eight…I didn’t go to the hotel because I didn’t want to
call you in the clear. We have to be the only people who know about
this…Because if anyone wanders into that site, anyone at all, and does
anything they shouldn’t, we will all die. I’m not saying they, I’m
saying we, and I’m not saying might die, I’m saying will die…Yes, this
is a Heavy Weapons alert…No, I can’t tell you what that means…All I
can tell you is that you must comply with the alert to the letter

The locals have indeed been using them as waste disposal units

“ – and then there are the undertakers,” continued Ngoyi. “They’ve
been using the machines for mass burials. Otherwise the bodies would
just have piled up in the streets in the epidemics. And the domestic
waste trucks, about five of them stop there several times a week and
dump stuff in through the skylights. And my own trucks – ”
“Your own trucks?”
“Yes. Three times a week, sometimes four or five.” Ngoyi returned
Mativi’s accusing stare.


Does it mention the size or mass of these black holes? It's tricky feeding matter into a tiny BH. A 500 million ton BH is about the size of a proton, and you can't lug something that heavy with a tractor. ;) https://www.vttoth.com/CMS/physics-notes/311-hawking-radiation-calculator

@PM2Ring I don't think scientific accuracy is this story's forte

Fictional problems require fictional solutions.

Thank you, Thats the one. Re reading it, its exactly the plot
https://www.theshortstory.org.uk/stories/downloads/green.pdf
